# Python 3 - ValueError int()base must be >=2 and <=36

Tags: python, python-3.x

I very much a noob so please forgive my scruffy confusing code. I am trying to make a game engine of my own for text based adventures with combat and such. here is the code:

```
import random

def drawBoard(board):
    # This function prints out the board that it was passed.
    # "board" is a list of 29 strings representing the board (ignore index 0)
    print('|---+---+---+---+---+---+---|')
    print('|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |')
    print('| ' + board[1] + ' | ' + board[2] + ' | ' + board[3] + ' | ' + board[4] + ' | ' + board[5] + ' | ' + board[6] + ' | ' + board[7] + ' | ')
    print('|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |')
    print('|---+---+---+---+---+---+---|')
    print('|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |')
    print('| ' + board[8] + ' | ' + board[9] + ' | ' + board[10] + ' | ' + board[11] + ' | ' + board[12] + ' | ' + board[13] + ' | ' + board[14] + ' | ')
    print('|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |')
    print('|---+---+---+---+---+---+---|')
    print('|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |')
    print('| ' + board[15] + ' | ' + board[16] + ' | ' + board[17] + ' | ' + board[18] + ' | ' + board[19] + ' | ' + board[20] + ' | ' + board[21] + ' | ')
    print('|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |')
    print('|---+---+---+---+---+---+---|')
    print('|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |')
    print('| ' + board[22] + ' | ' + board[23] + ' | ' + board[24] + ' | ' + board[25] + ' | ' + board[26] + ' | ' + board[27] + ' | ' + board[28] + ' | ')
    print('|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |')
    print('|---+---+---+---+---+---+---|')


def whoGoesFirst():
    if random.randint(0, 1) == 0: # coin flip 50/50 who starts combat
        firstToSpawn = enemy
        lastToSpawn = player
    else:
        firstToSpawn = player
        lastToSpawn = enemy

# following chunk works out the spawn points of the first to enter
#and the last to enter, respectively. It then places them on the
#board in their respective spawn points, represented by their symbol

while firstToSpawn not in theBoard and lastToSpawn not in theBoard:
    boardSpawn = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 14 21 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 15 8'.split()
    boardSpawnResult = random.choice(boardSpawn)
    theBoard[int(boardSpawnResult)] = firstToSpawn
    print(firstToSpawn + ' has entered the room.')

else:
    if firstToSpawn in theBoard and lastToSpawn not in theBoard:
        boardHalf = len(boardSpawn) / 2
        boardHalf = int(boardHalf)
        lastToSpawnPosition = int(boardSpawnResult) + boardHalf
        if lastToSpawnPosition > len(boardSpawn):
            lastToSpawnPosition = lastToSpawnPosition - len(boardSpawn)
            lastToSpawnPosition = boardSpawn[lastToSpawnPosition]
        theBoard[int(lastToSpawnPosition)] = lastToSpawn
        print(lastToSpawn + ' has entered the room.')
        if firstToSpawn == player:
            playerLocale = int(boardSpawnResult)
            global playerLocale
        else:
            playerLocale = int(lastToSpawnPosition)
            global playerLocale
        print(drawBoard(theBoard))


def shoot():
shotChance = int(playerStats[1]) - int(gangerStats[3])
didItHit = random.randint(int(shotChance), 100)
if didItHit < 65:
    print(playerName + ' Missed the shot!')
elif didItHit >= 65:
    didItCrit = random.randint(int(playerStats[5], 85))
    if didItCrit >= 85:
        shotDamage = 25 + weaponsGlock
        print('Critical hit! ' + shotDamage)
    else:
        shotDamage = weaponsGlock
        print(playerName + ' Hit the enemy for ' + shotDamage)

    gangerStats[0] - shotDamage
    if gangerStats[0] < 1:
        print(playerName + ' killed the Ganger!')

#declaring globals and starting the program
while True:
    theBoard = [' ']* 29
    player = ' '
    enemy = '!'
    print('What\'s your name, Droog?')
    playerName = input()
    player = playerName[0].upper()
    playerLocale = ' '
    playerStats = '100 50 2 10 5 2'.split()
    gangerStats = '65 20 1 5 3 5'.split()
    weaponsGlock = 30
    whoGoesFirst()
    shoot()
while int(gangerStats[0]) > 0:
    command = input('Type shoot to attack again:').lower
    if command == 'shoot':
        shoot()
else:
    if int(gangerStats[0]) <= 0:
        command = input('Type "searchbody" to loot dead enemies:').lower
```

The errors keep appearing for me in my shoot() function on the line where the randint is rolled for the didItCrit variable. Here's a copy of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 420, in run_nodebug
  File "C:\Python33\practice programs\textAdventure\combatmodule.py", line 163, in <module>
    shoot()
  File "C:\Python33\practice programs\textAdventure\combatmodule.py", line 133, in shoot
    didItCrit = random.randint(int(playerStats[5], 85))
ValueError: int() base must be >= 2 and <= 36
```

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `'65 20 1 5 3 5'.split()` instead of just `[65, 20, 1, 5, 3, 5]`?

Comment: simply because it means not having to type the list out. That's not a bad thing is it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You misplaced a `)`:

```
random.randint(int(playerStats[5], 85))
```

calls `int()` with 2 arguments. Instead, you want:

```
random.randint(int(playerStats[5]), 85)
```

which calls `randint()` with 2 arguments, 1 of which is the result of calling `int()` with 1 argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, much appreciated - problem fixed and it's back to simply moderately buggy now :D Cheers