# Why is the base value for int() limited to between 36 and 2

Tags: python, int, radix

I find that when I run the following expression in python

```
int(33, base=100)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: int() base must be >= 2 and <= 36, or 0
```

I could't find any explanation for this limitation; [another Stack Overflow question about the same error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629012/python-3-valueerror-intbase-must-be-2-and-36) doesn't mentioned why the base argument is limited to this range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: you can only specify a base for `int()` when converting **strings** into numbers. Say you have a string with a *hexadecimal* number, so base 16:

```
>>> int('2a', 16)
42
```

This result differs significantly from the same string interpreted as a different base:

```
>>> int('2a', 11)
32
>>> int('2a', 29)
68
```

You only ever need the base of an integer number when *presenting* the value visually or when parsing the integer value from a string representation. You can display an integer value in many different ways, but an `int` object is the value, not a visual presentations, and doesn't have a base nor can you change that base.

The logical extension when already supporting hexadecimal notation (digits 0-9 and letters A-F), is also support using the letters G-Z, and 10 digits and 26 letters makes it possible to use base 36:

```
>>> int('zz', 36)
1295
```

Further bases would need to use non-alphanumeric symbols, for which there is no clear pre-set ordering.

You can't have a base lower than 2; you *can't count* with just a single digit, the [value of `0`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0) will not change.

Comment: thanks for explanation, as mathematically it is possible to encode high value, was confused why it's limited here in python.

Answer (score 6):

The `base` argument to `int` is meant to be used when parsing a string, not when passing an int to `int`:

```
>>> int('ff', 16)
255
```

It's a well-established convention to use a, b, c, ..., z for digits representing 10, 11, 12, ..., 35, but there's no convention for what symbol to use for digit 36 in base 37.

Answer (score 3):

This is a practical implementation convention.  What do you envision as the character set for base 100?  :-)

Using digits and the entire alphabet is common enough, so the `base` function with a contiguous set of acceptable base values implemented the functionality that far.  Base 1 is simply len(arg).

There is also a convention for base-64 encoding; without a convention for the values 37-63, though, the `base` function left the radix-64 value for a separate interface.

Comment: The base64 encoding conventions (plural!) are incompatible with the usual mapping of symbols to digits, too - for example, the symbol `'0'` doesn't represent the value 0 in base64 encoding.

Comment: Right -- that wouldn't keep `base` from making the conversion, but the functionality would not be smooth over an apparently small parameter change.

Comment: @Prune i was just experimenting it out . as mathematically it's possible to encode it this high, was checking that in python whether this is possible or not.

Comment: Of course.  It's certainly possible -- but you need to have a convention for the textual representation.  There's an obvious interpretation *if* the input text is limited to the 36 or 64 characters already accepted.  However, since we do *not* have a convention for the other characters in an arbitrarily long set, the built-in functions don't support those bases.  Writing your own is easy, if you want that functionality.